# How to use CI4 parser service to render view from module

Tags: php, view, render, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to load views from module folder, since CI always look for views in App/View folder, how this can be overwritten to give complete path from ROOTPATH instead of APPPATH/Views

```
$parser = \Config\Services::parser();
$parser->setData(['variable' => $variable])->render('modules\PluginName\Views\index');
```

Error
CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException
Invalid file: {path/to/project}/app/Config/../Views/modules/PluginName/Views/index.php

Comment: Hi Syed! Have you tried to edit app/Config/Paths.php? In the last line there is a $viewDirectory parameter that could solve your problem. I haven't tested it yet, but you could use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a path relative to the default Views path.

You could either:

**1. Edit the line below in your Config/Path.php file in CodeIgniter 4 folder structure:**

```
public $viewDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../Views';
```

to

```
public $viewDirectory = '/modules/PluginName/Views';
```

From the comments in the file:
This variable must contain the name of the directory that contains the view files used by your application. By default this is in `app/Views`. This value
is used when no value is provided to `Services::renderer()`.

**or**

**2. Set it as an absolute path for that parser:**

```
$parser->setData(['variable' => $variable])->render('/modules/PluginName/Views/index');
```

Notice the slash / at the begining of the path.